# Eclipse: Enable Link With Editor on Startup

Tags: eclipse, editor

Since the update to Eclipse 2020-09, the Link with Editor feature is disabled by default on startup. How is it possible to enable this feature on startup so that I do not have to activate it manually every time I start Eclipse?

I use Eclipse with the SAP HANA Studio plugins, version 2.3.56. Does anybody have the same problem? Did anybody find a solution for this?

Comment: Eclipse 2020-09 is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. Use WebIDE for HANA development

Comment: Is it possible to edit BW objects, like IOBJs or ADSOs, in the WebIDE?

Comment: @SimonD. As far as I know, BW is still in Eclipse.